# One-click ASP.NET web-deploy including prerequisites?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, export, web-deployment

Is there a way to deploy a website so it creates an executable/batch that when executed on the server, will install all the prerequisites (i.e. .NET version, IIS, SQL, local permissions etc.)?

I'm looking for the ONE-CLICKER I can provide my client with, so he just double-clicks it and it's all there.

Comment: and DNS ? I think that what you looking for need totally custom program because its requires a lot of knowing of the server components, like the SQL type and version, the DNS server version and installation dir, the net version etc.... so start making it. (or use the Plesk, or something like Plesk)

Comment: I think DNS is out of scope, internal links should be shipped by the dev in-site, external domain name handling is handled by the provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using the [Web Deployment Project](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/05/26/visual-studio-2010-web-deployment-projects-rtw-available-now.aspx) in Visual Studio? Here's a good [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx) about it by Scott Hanselman.

Also I've heard good thigs about [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/).